# emacs equivalent of Xcode's #pragma mark?

Tags: linux, emacs, text-editors, xcode

I'm coming to emacs from Xcode.  An Xcode feature I really like is the ability to type the lines

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Section Heading Name
```

to mark the subsequent part of my code as belonging to a particular section.  I can then jump to that section from a drop-down menu.

Does a similar ability to break up code into named sections and to jump to a section by name exist in emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often called *folding*. There are several folding packages for Emacs.

- A commonly used package is the simply-named [folding](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode) package. It's not shipped with Emacs, you have to install it separately. Its preferred markers are `{{{` … `}}}` but they can be configured.
- You can use the built-in Outline minor mode. Set `outline-regexp` to `"#pragma mark"` and perhaps write an appropriate `outline-level`.
- You may also be interested in [`hs-minor-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow), [`hide-ifdef-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideIfDef), and [FoldDwim](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldDwim).

Answer (score 0):

`emacs` has something called `bookmarks`, maybe it can be useful, take a look [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookMarks) (or here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?(emacs)Bookmarks).

You can also type inside `emacs`:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> `bookmark` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

to see a list of functions about that.